# How to set a timer in solidity?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I am launching a game that should close after exactly 3 days/72 hours of initializing & deploying the contract.

My current thoughts are:

1. declare a variable, `timestamp`.
2. in the constructor, set the variable `timestamp` to `block.timestamp`
3. add 3 days worth of time [in milliseconds i presume] to the `timestamp` variable
4. do a `require(block.timestamp < timestamp)` in the game logic [users call a write function, so I can do it in there], so users cannot write the function if `block.timestamp` is past `timestamp + 3 days`

Is this is a feasible solution? Is there a better solution? Is there a more gas efficient solution?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote this:

```
  // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

    pragma solidity 0.8.0;
    contract MyContract{
        uint start;
        uint end;
        modifier timeIsOver{
            require(block.timestamp<=end,"Time is up");
            _;
        }
         // Firstly, call this 
        function startTimer() public{
            start=block.timestamp;
        }
        // Secondly, call this 
        // timestamp of the current block in seconds since the epoch
        // period is in seconds
        function endTimer(uint period) public {
            end=period+start;
        }

        function timeLeft() public view returns(uint){
            return end-block.timestamp;
        }

        function callThisWhenTimeIsUp() external timeIsOver{
            // write the logic here
        }

    }
```

Or you could use oracle to set up timer. Oracle is external serice that you use in ethereum. an example: https://blog.chain.link/blockchain-voting-using-a-chainlink-alarm-clock-oracle/

Answer (score 0):

```
// File: contracts/MyToken.sol

pragma solidity 0.8.16;


contract ICO {
    //Administration Details
    address public admin;
    address payable public ICOWallet;

    //Token
    IERC20 public token;

    //ICO Details
    uint public tokenPrice = 0.000000001 ether;
    uint public hardCap = 8 ether;
    uint public raisedAmount;
    uint public minInvestment = 0.005 ether;
    uint public maxInvestment = 1 ether;
    uint public icoStartTime;
    uint public icoEndTime;

    //Investor
    mapping(address => uint) public investedAmountOf;

    //ICO State
    enum State {
        BEFORE,
        RUNNING,
        END,
        HALTED
    }
    State public ICOState;

    //Events
    event Invest(
        address indexed from,
        address indexed to,
        uint value,
        uint tokens
    );
    event TokenBurn(address to, uint amount, uint time);

    //Initialize Variables
    constructor(address payable _icoWallet, address _token) {
        admin = msg.sender;
        ICOWallet = _icoWallet;
        token = IERC20(_token);
    }

    //Access Control
    modifier onlyAdmin() {
        require(msg.sender == admin, "Admin Only function");
        _;
    }

    //Receive Ether Directly
    receive() external payable {
        invest();
    }

    fallback() external payable {
        invest();
    }

    /* Functions */

    //Get ICO State
    function getICOState() external view returns (string memory) {
        if (ICOState == State.BEFORE) {
            return "Not Started";
        } else if (ICOState == State.RUNNING) {
            return "Running";
        } else if (ICOState == State.END) {
            return "End";
        } else {
            return "Halted";
        }
    }

    /* Admin Functions */

    //Start, Halt and End ICO
    function startICO() external onlyAdmin {
        require(ICOState == State.BEFORE, "ICO isn't in before state");

        icoStartTime = block.timestamp;
        icoEndTime = icoStartTime + (2 weeks);
        ICOState = State.RUNNING;
    }

    function haltICO() external onlyAdmin {
        require(ICOState == State.RUNNING, "ICO isn't running yet");
        ICOState = State.HALTED;
    }

    function resumeICO() external onlyAdmin {
        require(ICOState == State.HALTED, "ICO State isn't halted yet");
        ICOState = State.RUNNING;
    }

    //Change ICO Wallet
    function changeICOWallet(address payable _newICOWallet) external onlyAdmin {
        ICOWallet = _newICOWallet;
    }

    //Change Admin
    function changeAdmin(address _newAdmin) external onlyAdmin {
        admin = _newAdmin;
    }

    /* User Function */
    
    //Invest
    function invest() public payable returns (bool) {
        require(ICOState == State.RUNNING, "ICO isn't running");
        require(
            msg.value >= minInvestment && msg.value <= maxInvestment,
            "Check Min and Max Investment"
        );
        require(
            investedAmountOf[msg.sender] + msg.value <= maxInvestment,
            "Investor reached maximum Investment Amount"
        );

        require(
            raisedAmount + msg.value <= hardCap,
            "Send within hardcap range"
        );
        require(
            block.timestamp <= icoEndTime,
            "ICO already Reached Maximum time limit"
        );

        raisedAmount += msg.value;
        investedAmountOf[msg.sender] += msg.value;

        (bool transferSuccess, ) = ICOWallet.call{value: msg.value}("");
        require(transferSuccess, "Failed to Invest");

        uint tokens = (msg.value / tokenPrice) * 1e18;
        bool saleSuccess = token.transfer(msg.sender, tokens);
        require(saleSuccess, "Failed to Invest");

        emit Invest(address(this), msg.sender, msg.value, tokens);
        return true;
    }

    //Burn Tokens
    function burn() external returns (bool) {
        require(ICOState == State.END, "ICO isn't over yet");

        uint remainingTokens = token.balanceOf(address(this));
        bool success = token.transfer(address(0), remainingTokens);
        require(success, "Failed to burn remaining tokens");

        emit TokenBurn(address(0), remainingTokens, block.timestamp);
        return true;
    }

    //End ICO After reaching Hardcap or ICO Timelimit
    function endIco() public {
        require(ICOState == State.RUNNING, "ICO Should be in Running State");
        require(
            block.timestamp > icoEndTime || raisedAmount >= hardCap,
            "ICO Hardcap or timelimit not reached"
        );
        ICOState = State.END;
    }

    //Check ICO Contract Token Balance
    function getICOTokenBalance() external view returns (uint) {
        return token.balanceOf(address(this));
    }

    //Check ICO Contract Investor Token Balance
    function investorBalanceOf(address _investor) external view returns (uint) {
        return token.balanceOf(_investor);
    }
}
```

I just posted an ICO Contract with a 2 week timer as an example of using and changing states w/ a timer. Hope this helps!